# zef has failed to install Inline::Perl5 on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, raku, zef

I was trying to install `zef install Inline::Perl5` but it gives errors. How can I fix it ?

[image]

Comment: To add some more to the question: When I try to run `zef.bat install Inline::Perl5` on Windows 10 from Cygwin it fails with  `Failed to find dependencies: perl:from<native>`. The same error if I run from Windows CMD and from MSYS2 terminal window.

Comment: @HåkonHægland you would need `perl.dll`/`libperl.dynlib`/`libperl.so` available for NativeCall to find (see https://github.com/ugexe/zef/blob/602c54f1069631fd527473f4028451e5c47bc42c/lib/Zef/Client.rakumod#L1085-L1095 for the code used to check for native dependencies)

Comment: See also [can't install Inline::Perl5 by zef](https://github.com/ugexe/zef/issues/401)